# How to determine submission options for dropbox folder using Valence Api

Tags: dropbox, submission, valence

Is there a way using Valence Api to determine submission options for specific dropbox folder?

When creating folder there are option first if You can upload single file, or multiple, and then if you can submit as many times as You want, or only one. I am creating an application that communicates with D2L, and one of the functionalities is submiting assessments solutions. I would like to hide submit button if user has already submited the solution and he cannot submit any more. Also I would like to limit files if there can be only one.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [API info on Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557006/how-to-determine-submission-options-for-dropbox-folder-using-valence-api), that information is not included in the Dropbox folder attributes.